# My Postman for Postman REST API cannot seem to work

Tags: postman, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I would like to fetch payments by order. I do not receive any errors however the output i have gotten is different from what shown in https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/.

I was supposed to get a response of this

[Response from RazorPay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5di0.png)

Response i have gotten
[Response I have gotten instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUK5F.png)

does anyone where icould possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Please add code as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow
Can you share your curl?
and Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)